# how to create junit reports in eclipse?

Tags: selenium, junit, webdriver

I want to generate junit reports in eclipse. I generated build.xml, than run my tests. I perform the steps described here http://earlwillis.wordpress.com/2012/01/31/getting-started-with-junit-reports/. But I get error

```
Buildfile: E:\eclipse\WebDriver\build.xml
build-subprojects:
init:
build-project:
 [echo] WebDriver: E:\eclipse\WebDriver\build.xml
[javac] E:\eclipse\WebDriver\build.xml:45: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set,     defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
 build:
Sector:
[junit] Running Sector
[junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec
[junit] Test Sector FAILED
junitreport:
[junitreport] Processing E:\eclipse\WebDriver\junit\TESTS-TestSuites.xml to E:\DOCUME~1  \CONSUL~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\null35256633
[junitreport] Loading stylesheet jar:file:/E:/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.8.2.v20120109-1030/lib/ant-junit.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/junit/xsl/junit-frames.xsl
[junitreport] : Error! The first argument to the non-static Java function 'replace' is not a valid object reference.
[junitreport] : Error! Cannot convert data-type 'void' to 'reference'.
[junitreport] : Fatal Error! Could not compile stylesheet
[junitreport] Failed to process E:\eclipse\WebDriver\junit\TESTS-TestSuites.xml

BUILD FAILED
E:\eclipse\WebDriver\build.xml:193: Errors while applying transformations: Fatal error during transformation

Total time: 2 seconds
```

If needed I can provide build.xml. In folder junit I don't see  any html files. What I do wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536095/ant-junit-build-error-inside-eclipse

Comment: or: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10607151/error-the-first-argument-to-the-non-static-java-function-replace-is-not-a-val

Comment: unfortunatelly it is not helpful

Comment: @khris  did you refresh the project after you run the tests?