# Generate JUnit Test report

Tags: eclipse, junit

Is it possible to have JUnit Test report data in html in eclipse(kepler), which show many test case and how many passed, what is the intent of test cases etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can be done using Ant eclipse build file read more [here](http://earlwillis.wordpress.com/2012/01/31/getting-started-with-junit-reports/) the Ant build file generated from eclipse it self.

More References :

1)http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Ant/Junitreport.htm

2)http://earlwillis.wordpress.com/2012/01/31/getting-started-with-junit-reports/

3)http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junitreport.html

Hope that helps

Comment: [junitreport] : Error! The first argument to the non-static Java function 'replace' is not a valid object reference.
[junitreport] : Error! Could not compile stylesheet
[junitreport] : Fatal Error! Cannot convert data-type 'void' to 'reference'. Cause: Cannot convert data-type 'void' to 'reference'.
[junitreport] Failed to process C:\Users\gur35807\Desktop\WorkspaceM2MNew\M2MServiceCapabilityLayer\M2MTransport\M2MTransportContentBinding\M2MTransportContentBindingImplBundle\junit\TESTS-TestSuites.xml

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536095/ant-junit-build-error-inside-eclipse